# ASL Warnings but no application crash

Tags: ios, xcode-storyboard

I have been at this for couple of hours and have no clue on how to solve. I am seeing the following warning messages in my .asl file in Library/Logs directory.

```
Sep 28 21:16:44 MacBook-Pro.local SpringBoard[17848] <Warning>: *** error reading settings archive file: <SBRootSettings: /Users/{user}/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0-64/Documents/com.apple.springboard.settings/RootSettings.plist> 
Sep 28 21:16:49 MacBook-Pro.local SpringBoard[17848] <Warning>: Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
Sep 28 21:16:49 MacBook-Pro.local SpringBoard[17848] <Warning>: Using your own bundle identifier as an NSUserDefaults suite name does not make sense and will not work. Break on _NSUserDefaults_Log_Nonsensical_Suites to find this
Sep 28 21:16:49 MacBook-Pro.local SpringBoard[17848] <Warning>: Launch Services: Registering unknown app identifier com.apple.mobilemail failed
```

The application is not crashing. However, it is only displaying these logs. **Sometimes**, I see the following error message in my console area (after I have quit the simulator) :-

```
Terminating in response to Springboard's termination
```

I tried many times googling for that error but no luck. I am using a storyboard and my navigation controller has been set as initial view controller. Also, my storyboard has been setup as the main interface in deployment info. I have the following function in my delegate :-

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    return YES;
}
```

I am not sure if I have 1 problem or multiple problems. Can you please let me know how to proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

by reading **"Application windows are expected to have a root view controller"** 
i would think in your storyboard you need a view controller to have the box **"is Initial View Controller"** checked (it is under the property tag when clicking on a view controller class) or with in your application did launch do

```
[self.window setRootViewController:controller]
```

if you create the view controller in code.

Comment: yup. My navigation controller is already set to be "Initial view controller" in my storyboard

Comment: do you launch the app on a device or in the simulator? if it's on a device i would check the bundle identifier and make sure it is the same as your development provisioning files